# Prototype with a callback problem

Tags: prototype, namespaces, callback

```
function Foo() {
 this.bar = false;
}

Foo.prototype={
 onLoad: function() {
          this.bar=true;
         },

 create: function(id) {
          SomeClass.someMethod({
           id: id,
           onWorkIsDone: this.onLoad
          });
         }
};

var temp=new Foo();
temp.create();
```

This sample has a logic error in string 'onWorkIsDone: this.onLoad'. What I have to place instead of 'this.onLoad' to make SomeClass call exactly the temp.onLoad method when it finishes it's work?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're after...

```
function Foo() {
 this.bar = false;
}

var SomeClass = { someMethod: function(vars) {
                        vars.onWorkIsDone();
                    }
                }

Foo.prototype={
 onLoad: function() {
          alert("hello!");
         },

 create: function(id) {
          SomeClass.someMethod({
           id: id,
           onWorkIsDone: this.onLoad
          });
         }
};
```

are you calling the onWorkIsDone() method correctly?

Comment: Yes, the onWorkIsDone is called correctly, but if I put alert(this.bar) inside the onLoad function, it alerts 'undefined'. I'm absolutely sure there is a namespace error in defining callback function as this.onLoad, it should be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

```
    onWorkIsDone: (function() {
                        var self=this;
                        return function() {
                            self.onLoad()
                        }
                  }).call(this)
```

The simple closure did the trick.